# Can't install mssql-server in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, mysql, curl

```
telecast@telecast-PowerEdge-R210-II:~$ sudo curl -o /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Right now, your question lacks any helpful description. The good thing is, you can simply edit your question and include as much description as you like. Please take the time to explain what you are doing where you hit a problem. For example, which system is this? Is it a virtual machine? _Usually, TLS handshake problems are related to a wrong configured  MTU on an interface. Please read [about] and [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: are you using a http-proxy?